# Infinite running server-side python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, recursion, rhel

I want to replace Cron Jobs for "keeping" my program alive because it calls every XX interval whether or not the scrip is already called, creating duplicate entries.

I investigated the issue, and had a few approaches. One was to modify my program so it checks if it is already called and closes itself. The one I went after was to detach it completely from Cronjob by calling itself over and over again with `execfile` which works exactly how I want except the following problem:
`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Is there a way to keep the program in "infinite loop" without getting a Stack Overflow?

Here is my code, its a program that checks Mails, and converts them into MySQL DB entries.

```
imap = imaplib.IMAP4(hst)

try:
   imap.login(usr, pwd)
except Exception as e:
   errormsg = e
   time.sleep(30)
   print "IMAP error: " + str(errormsg)
   execfile('/var/www/html/olotool/converter.py')
   raise IOError(e)


# Authentification & Fetch Step

while True:

    time.sleep(5)
    '''
    The script will always result in an error if there
    are no mails left to check in the inbox. It then
    goes into sleep mode and relaunches itself to check
    if new mails have arrived.
    '''
    try:
        imap.select("Inbox") # Tell Imap where to go
        result, data = imap.uid('search', None, "ALL")
        latest = data[0].split()[-1]
        result, data = imap.uid('fetch', latest, '(RFC822)')
        raw = data[0][1] # This contains the Mail Data
        msg = email.message_from_string(raw)

    except Exception as e:
        disconnect(imap)
        time.sleep(60)
        execfile('/var/www/html/olotool/converter.py')
        raise IOError(e)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're raising an exception if there are no mails, and then relaunching the script.  Why don't you just check for new e-mails, and then only process the mail if `result` and `data` are not null?  If you want this to run forever, a simple `while True` with error checking on possible data outcomes would suffice.  If you want some sort of script management, you could use supervisord to ensure that you're script is running, and relaunch if it happens to crash on an unforeseen error.

Comment: cant check for only new mails because people are working with that inbox, I get like 20+ different types of mails into that inbox +/- 2000 per day and have to check each single mail if it is something I have to process or not. The script above is just a fraction, how the scripts starts and should end once it's done.  basically theres a whole bunch of stuff i have to check trough and then write the entry to MySQLdb. I know my way of doing it prolly sucks but I gotta start somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem myself with the only way I see it possible right now.
First I changed my exception in above code:

```
except Exception as e:
    disconnect(imap)
    print "Converter: No messages left"
    raise os._exit(0) 
    # This is a special case since this Exception is
    # no error thus os._exit(0) gives no false-positives
```

As you see I refrain from using `execfile` now. Instead I wrote a controller script that checks the status of my converter.py and launches it if it is not already running:

```
while True:

    presL = os.popen('pgrep -lf python').read()
    print "________________________________________"
    print "Starting PIDcheck"
    print "Current Processes: " 
    print presL # Check Processes

    presRconverter = find('\d{7} python converter.py', presL)
    if presRconverter:
        # Store the PID
        convPID = find('\d{7}', presRconverter)
        print "Converter is running at PID: " + convPID

    else:
        print "PID Controller: Converter not running"
        try:
            print "PID Controller: Calling converter"
            subprocess.check_call('python converter.py', shell=True)

        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            errormsg = e
            print "Couldn't call Converter Module"
            sendMail(esender,ereceiver,esubject,etext,server)
            print "Error notification send"
            raise IOError(e)

    # If we got until here without ERROR, the call was Successfull
    print "PID Controller: Call successful"
    print "________________________________________"
    time.sleep(60)
```

This method does not raise an: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Also this provides you with a `nohup.out` file if you run the controller with command `nohup python converter.py` where you can see any problems for errorhandling.

I hope I could help anyone running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this should work without having to resort to subprocess checking and such:

```
def check_mail_loop():
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4(hst)
    # Build some function to login, and, in the event of an error, sleep for n seconds and call login function again.
    imap.login(usr, pwd)

    while True:
        try:
            imap.select("Inbox")
            result, data = imap.uid('search', None, "ALL")

            if result and data:
                latest = data[0].split()[-1]
                result, data = imap.uid('fetch', latest, '(RFC822)')
                raw = data[0][1] # This contains the Mail Data
                msg = email.message_from_string(raw)
            time.sleep(5)
        except SomeRelevantException as e:
            logging.log(e)
            time.sleep(60)
            pass
```

In the event of some random error that you didn't foresee, use a process control manager like supervisord or monit.